# Axis PoE Camera works with PoE-Switch but does not using various PoE Injectors

Tags: power-over-ethernet, surveillance

I am trying to get a **AXIS M3007-P** surveillance camera to work with Power over Ethernet.

Connected to a *D-Link DGS-1210-10P PoE Switch* the camera just works perfectly fine.

However, the D-Link Switch is not available where the camera is going to be mounted, so I tried several PoE-Injectors amongst them

- ZyXEL PoE-12HP v2 PoE Injector
- SonicWALL 01-SSC-5546 PoE Injector 802.3AF Gigabit N
- LevelOne POI-3000 Gigabit High Power PoE Injector
- DIGITUS DN-95102 PoE Injector 100 MBit/s IEEE 802.3af

and some cheaper no-name ones. It's always the same picture: The camera LEDs say there is power (obviously) but no ethernet connection.

The data cables going to any of the PoE-injectors ran through a small desktop-sized unmanaged Netgear Switch and then to the very same managed Switch the D-Link PoE Switch is connected/uplinked to.

I've tried the same as well as different cables just to make sure I don't have a faulty cable in my setup.

To be honest I've no idea, not even a clue, what is going on here?

Any suggestions, please?

**Note**: There is no crossover cable involved at all. However, the RJ45-jack at the cameras cable is wired in tia-568a mode and all the other cables are wired in tia-568b. As far as I know this should not be any problem, as long as the two standards are not mixed within the two ends of one cable?

Comment: I see you've tried multiple cables, but any chance this could be a straight vs crossover issue ? Some of those PoE injectors explicitely specify you should use a straight cable between them and the PoE device, even though the standard says that MDIX auto and crossover cables should be able to work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem - maybe this can help someone else in a similar situation. The AXIS camera model mentioned does not come with a PoE Port/Socket but a short Ethernet cable coming directly out of the casing. The problem was a loose connection within this "hardwired" part of the cable which i found out rather coincidentally when i bent the cable in a certain direction and the camera suddenly worked! Thanks everybody